# How to bind selection of combobox in itemscontrol to different list than used as itemssource in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

this is concerning WPF and MVVM,

I have a list of items that are unsorted (e.g., "item3, item2, item5, item1, item4"). For each item, I want to display a number of comboboxes equal to the number of items (for *n* items there needs to be *n* comboboxes). The user then selects an item for each combo box, essentially sorting the list (resulting in a list of "item1, item2, Item3, item4, item5."). The sorted values are then stored in another list of items. Sorting has to be done by the user.

I have a ViewModel that contains both lists, one with the unsortedItems, the sortedList initially a copy to be the same size.

I manually created a combo box for each item, all with the same Itemssource bound to the unsorted list of items. I then bound each combo box SelectedItem with an index representing which combobox it was i.e., for the first combo box SelectedItem="{binding SortedList[0]}".

The problem with this approach is that I don't know how many items there will be. I thought an Itemscontrol would do the job here but I can't seem to figure out how to embed a combobox inside an itemscontrol so that I can use DisplayMemberPath and SelectedItem properly and not share the selected value. This is what I tried:

## Item

```
public class Item
    {
        public Item(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
    }
```

## Item Selection Part

```
 public class ItemSelectionPart
    {
        public ItemSelectionPart(List<Item> allItems)
        {
            this.allItems = allItems;
        }

        public List<Item> allItems { get; set; }

        public Item Selection { get; set; }


    }
```

## ViewModel

```
public class ComboViewModel
    {
        public string test2 { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<ItemSelectionPart> ItemsSelection { get; set; }

        public ComboViewModel()
        {
            test2 = "test";
            items = new List<Item>
                    {
                        new Item(100, "Entry #1"),
                        new Item(101, "Entry #2"),
                        new Item(102, "Entry #3"),
                        new Item(103, "Entry #4")

                    };

            ItemsSelection = new ObservableCollection<ItemSelectionPart> (Enumerable.Repeat(new ItemSelectionPart(items), items.Count));
        }

    }
```

## Main Window Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestingComboBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingComboBox"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ComboViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl
            x:Name="level1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSelection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ComboBox
                            x:Name="Combo"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=allItems}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=allItems.Id}"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Selection}">                           

                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

*I know that displaymemberpath doesn't work - but left there for what I intended*

## Main Window.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ComboViewModel D;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            D = new ComboViewModel();
            this.DataContext = D;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with share is, that with `Enumerable.Repeat(new ItemSelectionPart(items), items.Count)` you create an enumeration with same instance `new ItemSelectionPart(items)`. Later you use the same instance by each combobox, modifying it you impact all comboboxes.

`DisplayMemberPath` gets just string, not binding.

See the fix:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSelection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ComboBox
                x:Name="Combo"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=allItems}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Selection}">
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

public ComboViewModel()
{
    test2 = "test";
    items = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item(100, "Entry #1"),
                new Item(101, "Entry #2"),
                new Item(102, "Entry #3"),
                new Item(103, "Entry #4")
            };
    var selPartList = new List<ItemSelectionPart>(items.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        selPartList.Add(new ItemSelectionPart(items));
    }
    ItemsSelection = new ObservableCollection<ItemSelectionPart>(selPartList);
    //ItemsSelection = new ObservableCollection<ItemSelectionPart>(Enumerable.Repeat(new ItemSelectionPart(items), items.Count));
}
```